# Cursor became cross-mark

Tags: cursor

Suddenly my cursor in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS has become a cross mark in gnome-desktop. I've just installed `oneko`. Does this have something to do with the cursor?

Comment: I just installed `oneko` and I don't have the problem, so it's likely something else causing the problem.

Comment: @Donarsson: Not necessary, you may have a different system configuration than the OP.

Comment: I have resolved it my changing my cursor theme in gnome-tweak-tool

Comment: Can you please post your solution as an answer so others can benefit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install gnome-tweak-tool and then go to appearance tab and change the cursor theme to some other theme and back to the original one.
That solved my problem.