# Why does my cursor keep changing to a black cross and how do I revert it?

Tags: mouse, 16.10

When it is in black cross mode I can't click on anything and have to do a hard reboot to fix the issue.

Please see a picture of the issue here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KL8u1.jpg

Comment: What programs does that happen in? Or does it happen in different programs?

Comment: Both times it happened while using Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and can't find a solution for it.

Doesn't solve the black cross directly, but it makes a very quick system reset:

```
sudo service dbus restart
```

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary resolve to the issue you can type in the Terminal `sudo service lightdm restart` which should work.

Answer (score 0):

According to [M. Tarun](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453934/cursor-became-cross-mark), gnome-tweak-tool -> appearance tab -> change your cursor theme Cursor also works.